# Copying files in php

Tags: php, copy

I know that the copy() function does not allow directories to be listed first, but is there any way to bypass this? I am attempting to copy a file from one directory to a different directory, so I need to be able to state where the file should be copied from and to. Here is the code I have:

```
if ($_FILES["pdfFile"]["type"] == "application/pdf") 
{ 
   if (file_exists("../pdf_new/".$rowApp['fileName'])) 
   { 
       copy("../pdf_new/".$rowApp['fileName'], "../pdf_new/backup/".$rowApp['fileName']); 
   } 
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pdfFile"]["tmp_name"], "../pdf_new/".$rowApp['fileName']); 
 }
```

I tried replacing "../pdf_new" with a variable and then adding a "/" between the variable and the .$rowApp['fileName'], but it still did not work. Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by _does not allow directories to be listed first_? I don't see any such restriction in the documentation. I think your code should work.

Comment: You can copy a file from one directory to another http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772769/how-to-copy-a-file-from-one-directory-to-another-using-php

Comment: this is the warning message I receive:
"Warning: copy(): The first argument to copy() function cannot be a directory" and the file is unsuccessfully copied

Comment: what is in $rowApp['fileName'] in the case you describe?

Comment: I got it to copy, but the warnings still show up. Is there any way to stop them from showing?