# Storing the path of the file in SQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to save uploaded files by the users of the website to my database. I already did that using longblob (binary), however I'm interested in saving the path of the uploaded files instead.

This is my code, what modifications should I perform?

```
<?php require_once('Connections/databasestudents.php'); ?>
<?php

$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

$fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$content = addslashes($content);

$studentId = $_POST['studentId'];
fclose($fp);

$query = "INSERT INTO file (studentId, fileName, fileType, fileContent ) ".
"VALUES ('$studentId', '$fileName', '$fileType', '$content')";

mysql_select_db($database_databasestudents, $databasestudents);
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed'); 

header("Location: students.php");
die();

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not code ready for production.

Given that, basically what you need is to upload the files using `move_uploaded_file`. Just a basic snippet using your code is:

```
require_once('Connections/databasestudents.php');

if($_FILES)
{
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

    // $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    // $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    // $content = addslashes($content);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name']))
    {
        $studentId = $_POST['studentId'];
        // fclose($fp);

        $query = "INSERT INTO file (studentId, fileName, fileType, fileContent ) ".
        "VALUES ('$studentId', '$fileName', '$fileType', '$content')";

        mysql_select_db($database_databasestudents, $databasestudents);
        mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed'); 

        header("Location: students.php");
        die();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, so in the database, I found the new uploaded file under the correct id. The file name is saved correctly. However the file content is empty and the file type is filled with this (image/png).
Also, when I try to retrieve (download) the uploaded file it shows the file is corrupted. seems something wrong with the uploading process.. any idea why?

Comment: After the `if($_FILES)` insert `var_dump($_FILES);`. This returns an array which contains your file data as filesize, error, etc. The `type` is the MIME-type of the file you have uploaded, so image/png

Comment: but the file content is zero..? Should I create a new field for file path in the database for example? I can't see any path stored.
Sorry for the inconvenience but I'm new to both PHP and SQL

Comment: Could you please post what's returning `var_dump($_FILES);`?

Comment: array (size=1)
  'file' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string 'basem.png' (length=9)
      'type' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
      'tmp_name' => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\phpEADA.tmp' (length=23)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 20709

Comment: So, it seems that no error is occurring there. Now by letting running the code until `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name'])` can you verify that this file does exists in the same dir where you have this code?

Comment: You can check the path and the file existence by adding `var_dump(realpath($_FILES['file']['name']));` right next `if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name']))
 {`

Answer (score 0):

Just two things:

1. Instead of reading the uploaded file's content you should copy the temp file to its final location.  Discussed in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772769/how-to-copy-a-file-from-one-directory-to-another-using-php)
2. Instead of inserting the content of the file you should store the filename, or the path you copied the temp file to.

The biggest challenge here is probably how to handle file name collisions (what should happen when 2 files with the same name are uploaded).  How you handle this situation depends entirely on the application.  When all files should be stored, even if their filename is identical to one formerly uploaded, you can always add a formatted timestamp to the filename, or some other piece of data that makes it unique (I've used a combination of date and PID before)