# Copy PHP to new directory , possible?

Tags: php

just now I learnt how to create new directory in the server.
So my question is it possible to copy a PHP file to the new directory created ?

Here's what i come up with

```
    mkdir('/home/user/public_html/ref/' . $cid . "_" . $gid, 0777);
   copy('/home/user/public_html/ref/index.php' ,'/home/user/public_html/ref/' . $cid . "_" . $gid);
```

Comment: Why not try it first and see if it works or not. If it doesn't work, post the error here asking for help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772769/how-to-copy-a-file-from-one-directory-to-another-using-php

Comment: And please do not ask all 5 minutes a new question! Ask google...

Comment: @LatheesanKanes ,Warning: copy(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in /home/user/public_html/index.php on line 15

Comment: @Dinistro, tried doing those even this : http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

but nothing helps for my situation.. i've been doing this project like 2 days and can't crack it.

Comment: @user3530739, it seems, that the second argument is a directory, you need to had a folder. try this: `'/home/user/public_html/ref/' . $cid . "_" . $gid . "/new.php"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct to use `copy()` see PHP docs on copy [here.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)

The example they offer is...

```
<?php
  $file = 'example.txt';
  $newfile = 'example.txt.bak';

  if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
      echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
  }
?>
```

Your syntax is incorrect as the 2 argument in `copy()` needs to be the file name no the directory (as in example above). So try this.

```
      mkdir('/home/user/public_html/ref/' . $cid . "_" . $gid, 0777);
   copy('/home/user/public_html/ref/index.php' ,'/home/user/public_html/ref/' . $cid . "_" . $gid . '/index.php');
```

Comment: No worries, I know how it can be when you are looking at yourself over and over and can't see issues!