# PHP Copy a file and rename with date and time

Tags: php

How can I copy and rename a file from `Data/Results/result.txt` to `Data/Results` `History/2014-11-13-12-00_result.txt` ? My code isn't working.

```
$path = "Data/Results/"; // Upload directory
        $tpath = "Data/Results History/"; // Upload to History Folder
        $name = "result.txt";
        $source = $path.$name;
        $today = date("d-m-Y");
        $time = date("H-i-s");
        $newname = $today."_".$time."_".$name;
        $dest = $tpath.$name;
        copy($source,$dest);
        $rename = $tpath.$newname;
        rename($dest,$rename);
```

Comment: What's the error returned?

Comment: also check the permission of the destination folder

Comment: use file_put_contents() , but you take this file from uploader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use rename

just simple use

```
// Will copy foo/test.php to bar/test.php
// overwritting it if necessary
copy('foo/test.php', 'bar/test.php');
```

[SO ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5772780/2810918)

Answer (score 1):

Your `$source` and `$destination` seem to be exactly the same, which won't work if you want the file to be copied to another destination. Along with that, you should use `copy()` to copy and move a file. `rename()` simply moves a file without copying it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<?php
$file = $path.'example.txt';
$newfile = $tpath.'example.txt.bak';

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a space in your $tpath, did u try

```
 $tpath = "Data/Results_History/";
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename should work, check the specified file permission and path is correct

```
if(file_exists($dest)){
 rename($dest,$rename);
}else{ 
// File not exists
}
```