# Copy image from one folder to another in PHP

Tags: php, file, copy

I have a default image in an `images/` folder.

When someone registers it creates a directory like so:

```
mkdir("../users/$new_userid/images",0755);
```

Each time someone registers, I want the default image to be copied to the new users directory, so they then have an image to start off with.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: Probably http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy a file from one directory to another using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772769/how-to-copy-a-file-from-one-directory-to-another-using-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would abstract out the user location so you have:

```
$new_user_folder = "../users/$new_userid/images";
mkdir($new_user_folder,0755);
```

That way you can re-use $new_user_folder and if you need to change it, you only change one var.

Then do something like (where $original_file is the exact filename of the one you want copied):

```
copy($original_file, $new_user_folder);
```

Note: not tested, but you get the idea