# copying file from one location to another location in an same server through php code

Tags: php

i want to copy a file from SRC to DEST. i have tried copy(src,dest) in php but it returns wrapper error (HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections).  What should i do to bypass this or any other way to achieve?

i have tried 1.file_put_contents('h/attach/file.pdf','/home/example/public_html/pq/p/ph/files');
2.copy('h/attach/file.pdf','https://example.org/pq/p/ph/files/file.pdf');

```
$urlsample="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf";
$labelpdf_name = "Sheet.pdf";
$labelfilelocation="attach/".$labelpdf_name;
$downloadedFileContents = file_get_contents($urlsample);
file_put_contents($labelfilelocation,$downloadedFileContents);
```

after downloading the pdf file now i need to copy this file to the respt dest.so i tried like below.

file_put_contents($labelfilelocation,'/home/example/public_html/pq/p/ph/files');
copy($labelfilelocation,'https://example.org/pq/p/ph/files'.$labelpdf_name);

i expect that the file from src should be created in dest folder.

Comment: You cannot copy to a HTTP(S) url. If it's on your own server, copy to the *local* file system path: `copy($labelfilelocation, '/home/example/public_html/pq/p/ph/files/'.$labelpdf_name);`

Answer (score 0):

According to solution provided here by super global **(Pascal MARTIN)** . [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772769/how-to-copy-a-file-from-one-directory-to-another-using-php)

You can use copy function like you did but you will have to create destination folder manually if it does not exist.

So your problem might be solved by manually creating your destination directory and then run copy method

```
// Will copy foo/test.php to bar/test.php
// overwritting it if necessary
copy('foo/test.php', 'bar/test.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You coud do this.

```
$src = 'filesource.pdf';
$destination = 'destinationfolder/filename.pdf';
if(!copy($src,$destination))
{
    echo "Error when copying $src";
}
else
{
    echo "$src copied in $destination";
}
```