# File transfer from one directory to another project directory using php

Tags: php

I wanna transfer a file from one project directory to another project directory. Here i tried to use copy() function but failed. Later i used move_uploaded_file. Here also failed. I guess , its pretty simple but unable to me for solving. Here is my code.

```
 $newPath = '././project_b/uploads/images/1582353992_flowers_yellow_blossom_windy_nature_434.mp4';         
 $sourcePath="/public/Files/Compress_video/1582353992_flowers_yellow_blossom_windy_nature_434.mp4";
 $upload = move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, $newPath);
```

Here $newPath is my send project directory and $sourcePath is first project.

Hope you got my point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy a file from one directory to another using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772769/how-to-copy-a-file-from-one-directory-to-another-using-php)

Comment: try to use check `if ( file_exists($source_path) )`