# Copy a file from one folder to another in php

Tags: php, file, copy

I have a problem when I want to copy a file from one folder to another on my website, I don't know what I'm doing wrong,the file is called "installed" and dont have extension, is only archive,I need to copy this file from the "ins" folder to the "var" folder this is the php code I'm using:

```
<?php
$file = '/../domains/travianforce.com.es/public_html/ins/installed';
$new_file = '/../domains/travianforce.com.es/public_html/var/';

if (!copy($file, $new_file)) {
    echo "Error to copy $file...\n";
}
?>
```

but when I run the script it gives me an error, I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I need your help, thank you very much! =)

Comment: Your path make no sense - `/../domains` is an absolute path with the directory above the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Give full path in **$file** and **$new_file**
And ans already given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772769/how-to-copy-a-file-from-one-directory-to-another-using-php)